# Android image copy breaks original file

Tags: android, android-image, android-gallery

I have found that if I have a WhatsApp image that I want to copy into a different folder on my Android device, keeping the original in place, then the date and time changes for the image.

So if I go into the phones gallery the date and time of both the images show the time of when I have copied the file. Why does copying break the original image? And lose important data on when the images were originally taken.

If I delete the second copied image, so only the original is the there, then the date and time reverts back to the original date and time when viewed in the gallery. It looks like the gallery when displaying the file date and time.is looking at the wrong version of the file??

I have tested this on multiple devices now and the same happens.

Comment: There are always two file times. Creation time and last access time. Let your file manager display both or the one you wish.

Comment: `then the date and time reverts back to the original date and time` That all is hard to believe.

Comment: Better show your copy code.

Comment: This isn't running through my code. Connect device to computer, copy a what's app image, as only breaks if a WhatsApp image, to a new folder. Now go to androids native photo gallery. The look at both the original and copied one and the gallery will display the copied date. Delete the one just copied and the original date time in the native gallery reverts the original. The same is happening on 3 different devices, all been Motorola though. Android 7,9 and 10.

Comment: Then you are in the wrong forum as this here is for programmers.

Comment: I am a programmer, I noticed this originally in my app I wrote. When calling cameraroll.save in react native, to copy an image leaving the original unchanged. It creates a copy but the originals date changes. I wanted to rule out my app, so did the above test.